# Shortcut icon not loading properly in electron-packager

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

## Explanation

I'm trying to run electron-packager in my project, currently using a windows x64 and compiling a ia32 version, this is the package config inside my package.json:

```
"package": "electron-packager ./ --prune=true --arch=ia32 --win32metadata.ProductName=myProdName --icon=favicon.ico --overwrite=true"
```

The problem is, when the project is compiled the icon isn't displayed properly, but if I go in the properties the icon is the one selected, see the images below:

#### Icon displayed in the folder

https://image.prntscr.com/image/cXekfe0QTCa_wFY-LZs1IQ.png

#### Icon displayed in properties

https://image.prntscr.com/image/IHWu6xQDRy_acEhvCCw1IQ.png

Would like to get some help in this, really don't know what more can I do to get this right.

Comment: If the icon is wrong in the Explorer, but correct when inspecting it, then it could also be a problem with the Windows icon cache. You can check by either copying the packaged app to a different location or by refreshing the icon cache.

Comment: I tried to refresh the icon cache on windows and restarting twice, didn't work. Although my answer bellow is right, when installed the same error occurs, I used squirrel for post-installing configs and the shortcut created displays with the wrong icon but in the folder (and in properties) the icon is the right one. After a while the icon defaults to the right one, I guess this is a problem caused by windows, nothing to do here. But thanks for the awnser anyways @RoyalBingBong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the error, it was in my package JSON.
Instead of:

```
   --icon=favicon.ico
```

It sould be:

```
    --icon=./favicon.ico
```

Needs the ./ in the start to identify